# x86 64bit Puzzle Program instruction operands must be same size

Tags: assembly, x86, syntax-error, masm

I am trying to get the following x86 64bit assembly code to compile in MASM (Visual studio)

```
.data
check   db  "1   2   3   4",10,"  5   6   7   8",10,"  9  10  11  12",10," 13  14  1"
puzzle  db  27,"c",10,"  1   2   3   4",10,"  5   6   7   8",10,"  9  10  11  12",10," 13  14  15    ",10,10
    db  " Direction ?",13             
    db  " Well done !  ",10,10
inKey   dw  0,0,0,0




.code
main PROC

_start:
    mov rax,100
    syscall
    mov rcx,rax
    shr rcx,3
    and rcx,255
    and rax,31
    lea rsi,[_start+rax]
    mov rbx,15
 
Mixing: 
    push    rcx
    mov di, [rsi+rcx*2]
    mov rcx,8

quatre: 
    mov ax,di
    shr di,2
    and ax,3
    add ax,65
    call    SWAPPIN
    loop    quatre
    pop rcx
    loop    Mixing
    cmp cx,ax
 
MainLp: 
    mov rdx,80  
Succes: 
    lea rsi,[puzzle]
    mov rdi,1
    mov rax,1
End?:   
    syscall
    mov rax,60
    je  End?
    mov rdx,8
    lea rsi,[inKey]
    mov rdi,0
    mov rax,0
    syscall
    mov al, [rsi+rax-2]
    call    SWAPPIN
    lea     rsi,[check]
    lea rdi,[puzzle+5]
    mov rcx,7
    repe    cmpsq
    jne MainLp
    mov rdx,95
    jmp Succes
 
SWAPPIN:
    mov rdx,rbx
    cmp al,"A"
    jne NotUp
    add rbx,4
    cmp rbx,16
    cmovae  rbx,rdx
NotUp:  
    cmp al,"B"
    jne NotDwn  
    sub rbx,4
    cmovc   rbx,rdx 
NotDwn: 
    cmp al,"C"
    jne NotLft
    test    rbx,3
    jz  Endcll
    dec rbx
NotLft: 
    cmp al,"D"
    jne Endcll
    inc rbx
    test    rbx,3
    cmovz   rbx,rdx
Endcll: 
    mov ax,"  "
    xchg    ax,[puzzle+4+rbx*4]
    mov [puzzle+4+rdx*4],ax
    ret


main ENDP
END
```

However I am getting an error on these 2 lines in the `Endcll:`

```
xchg    ax,[puzzle+4+rbx*4]
mov [puzzle+4+rdx*4],ax
```

The error is the same for both lines, it is:

```
1>Engine.asm(91): error A2022: instruction operands must be the same size
```

Can someone fix this code or explain to me why this `[puzzle+4+rdx*4]` is not the same size as `ax` or why this instruction is not working? Thank you.

Please refer to this [code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/15_puzzle_game#X86_64_Assembly)

Comment: MASM magically associates a size with a label name based on the `db` or `dw` or whatever.  Just use `word ptr` to override that, or use a different assembler if you don't like it.

Comment: Oh, you got that code from a web site.  That's not a Windows program, it's for GNU/Linux.  Note the use of `rax=100` / `syscall` to invoke `times(2)`.  It looks like NASM or maybe FASM source, not MASM, hence the errors when you try to assemble it after only porting parts of it.  Also, that's not strictly a *syntax* error, it's a semantic error.  A *syntax* error would be something that makes the code not even parse, like `[puzzle + 4 + 4*rdx [`

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you for this useful information. Are there any resources you could point me to that could help me port different assembler code (GNU/MASM/NASM) to work with the borland TASM assembler (specifically). And thank you again.

Comment: TASM can't make 64-bit code AFAIK.  If you mean to run in 16-bit mode, the system-calls available are completely different as well, so you'd have to rewrite any I/O code and other interaction with the system.  TASM is pretty much the same as MASM syntax, so you don't need to port that, per se, if you do already have 16-bit MASM code.  IDK if anyone's written guides to back-porting modern code to obsolete systems like DOS.  There are some links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info but they mostly teach you how to use one assembler, so learn both and then you'll know how to port.